# При отладке не видны значения глобальных переменных

Tags: c++, qt, отладка, qtcreator

После visual studio не очень понятно почему в qt при отладке мне не видны значения глобальных переменных.
[image: Что...]

В чем проблема?
(Да,знаю там написано "локальные"... и что мне все равно делать?!)

Comment: Можно перестать использовать глобальные переменные.

Comment: э-э-э-э-э... нет

Comment: Не понял. На вашем скриншоте показано значение некой локальной переменной `Near`. И оно видно. Как эта переменная относится к вопросу? Что вы ожидали там увидеть? И как это связано с Visual Studio???

Comment: FirstCost,SecCost,ThirCost

Comment: Прекрасно. Но я не вижу никаких попыток с вашей стороны посмотреть эти переменные. Почему это вдруг они должны быть видны в окне локальных переменных? И почему упомянуто Visual Studio? В Visual Studio вы тоже не увидите глобальных переменных в окне локальных.

Comment: Может поможете?

Comment: Вам же написали, что это окно локальных переменных, поэтому нет ничего удивител ного в том, что в нем не показываются глобальные переменные.

Comment: а где взять окно с глобальными???????

Comment: @One-Original-Name: С чего вы взяли, что такое окно вообще должно быть? Если вы хотите смотреть значения глобальных переменных, то их надо вручную добавить в соответствующее окно watch ("Выражения"?). Также, насколько я знаю, в Qt можно наводить на переменную мышкой, чтобы увидеть ее значение.

Answer (score 2):

Автоматом creator static и extern не показывает, надо перетащить нужную переменную drag-n-drop-ом в выражения или создать выражение ПКМ